# Matching any word enclosed in parentheses in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a regex to match any word enclosed in parentheses in a sentence.

Suppose, I have a sentence.

```
"Welcome, (Hello, All of you) to the Stack Over flow."
```

Say if my matching word is `Hello,`, `All`, `of` or `you`. It should return true.
Word could contain anything number , symbol but separated from other by white-space

I tried with this `\(([^)]*)\)`. but this returns all words enclosed by parentheses

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string ss = "Welcome, (Hello, All of you) to the Stack Over flow.";
            Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)");
            Match match = _regex.Match(ss.ToLower());
            if (match.Success)
            {
                ss = match.Groups[0].Value;
            }

        }
```

Help and Guidance is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Thanks People for you time and answers. I have finally solved by changing my code as reply by Tim.
For People with similar problem. I am writing my final code here

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ss = "Welcome, (Hello, All of you) to the Stack Over flow.";
            Regex _regex = new Regex(@"[^\s()]+(?=[^()]*\))");
            Match match = _regex.Match(ss.ToLower());
            while (match.Success)
            {
                ss = match.Groups[0].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(ss);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }

        }
```

Comment: show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Can there be (nested parentheses (like this)), and if so, which of these words should be matched?

Comment: i hope there is not a case for nested one

Comment: Even if you do get a solution in regex would it be more readable and maintainable to do it in code instead?

Comment: @CodeBlend Trying to avoid few lines of code for re-comparing if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it seems that a "word" is anything that's not whitespace and doesn't contain parentheses, and that you want to match a word if the next parenthesis character that follows is a closing parenthesis.

So you can use

```
[^\s()]+(?=[^()]*\))
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^\s()]+` matches a "word" (should be easy to understand), and
- `(?=[^()]*\))` makes sure that a closing parenthesis follows:

  ```
  (?=       # Look ahead to make sure the following regex matches here:
   [^()]*   # Any number of characters except parentheses
   \)       # followed by a closing parenthesis.
  )         # (End of lookahead assertion)
  ```

Comment: would this match only words that are contain in the parentheses?

Comment: Yes (assuming all parentheses are correctly balanced and unnested). Try it!

Comment: With my code and your regex, it returns only the first word.

Comment: @MillerKoijam: You are only doing one match operation. You need to repeat that if you want more than one (until `match.Success` is False).

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: @MillerKoijam: Use `while` instead of `if` and do `match = _regex.NextMatch();` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @MillerKoijam can i include your regex in my answer ?

Comment: @Amit Joki please do so

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a c# function for you, if you are interested.

```
public static class WordsHelper
{
    public static List<string> GetWordsInsideParenthesis(string s)
    {
        List<int> StartIndices = new List<int>();
        var rtn = new List<string>();
        var numOfOpen = s.Where(m => m == '(').ToList().Count;
        var numOfClose = s.Where(m => m == ')').ToList().Count;
        if (numOfClose == numOfOpen)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfOpen; i++)
            {
                int ss = 0, sss = 0;
                if (StartIndices.Count == 0)
                {
                    ss = s.IndexOf('(') + 1; StartIndices.Add(ss);
                    sss = s.IndexOf(')');
                }
                else
                {
                    ss = s.IndexOf('(', StartIndices.Last()) + 1;
                    sss = s.IndexOf(')', ss);
                }
                var words = s.Substring(ss, sss - ss).Split(' ');
                foreach (string ssss in words)
                {
                    rtn.Add(ssss);
                }
            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Just call it this way:

```
var text = "Welcome, (Hello, All of you) to the (Stack Over flow).";
            var words = WordsHelper.GetWordsInsideParenthesis(s);
```

Now you'll have a list of words in `words` variable.

*Generally, you should opt for c# coding, rather than regex because c# is far more efficient and readable and better than regex in performance wise.*

But, if you want to stick on to Regex, then its ok, do the following:

If you want to use regex, keep the regex from Tim Pietzcker `[^\s()]+(?=[^()]*\))` but use it this way:

```
var text="Welcome, (Hello, All of you) to the (Stack Over flow).";
var values= Regex.Matches(text,@"[^\s()]+(?=[^()]*\))");
```

now `values` contains `MatchCollection`

You can access the value using index and Value property

Something like this:

```
string word=values[0].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for regex. I have already have c# solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[(])[^)]+(?=[)])
```

Matches all words in parentheses

`(?<=[(])` Checks for `(`

`[^)]+` Matches everything up to but not including a `)`

`(?=[)])` Checks for `)`

Comment: This returns all text inside the text, same result as my question

Comment: What were you trying to return?

Comment: I was trying to get word by word. please see my edited question.

Comment: Touche! Atleast you found an answer:-)

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, dont remove your answer, it may help other if they want to extract all words enclosed by parentheses/other character.